# SelectSingleNode without namespace

Tags: .net, xml

I'm using .Net 2.0, and need to `SelectSingleNode` from my `XmlDocument` regardless of namespace, as wrong headed as that may sound.

to be specific

```
XmlElement slipType = (XmlElement)document.SelectSingleNode("//Provenance1");
```

will set `slipType` to null since I don'l know th namespace Provenance1 is in at the time of the query.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can check the **[local-name](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#function-local-name)** of the element and ignore namespace with the following XPath expression:

```
//*[local-name()='Provenance1']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
XmlElement slipType = (XmlElement)document.SelectSingleNode("//*:Provenance1");
```

Or:

```
XmlElement slipType = (XmlElement)document.SelectSingleNode("//@*:Provenance1");
```

for attributes...

Unfortunately, this construction would only work with XPath 2.0, while .NET uses only XPath 1.0. I accidently tested above code with a 2.0 parser, so it doesn't work.)

Comment: This throws an XPathException //*:Provenance1 has an invalid token.

Comment: I've tested it with .NET 3.5, where it crashed too. However, it is a valid XPath construction. Unfortunately for XPath 2.0, which I had tested. But .NET uses only XPath 1.0 and it's unlikely .NET will support 2.0...