# How to find the namesapce of a tag in xml using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I want to remove some tags from an xml. I'm using selectNodes() but I need to pass the namespace. So I tried to get the namespace by using GetXmlNamespaces(). some of the namespaces do not have a key value. And I can not provide the namespace as a hard coded value and need to change the namespace regularly. The only values I can pass are the tag name and the file. Is there anyway I can get the namespace a tag belongs to in c#?

for example I'm passing this namespace as a hardcoded value but I need to do it programmatically.

```
        var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("a", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main");

        XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//a:workbook/a:fileVersion", nsmgr);
```

this namespace 'xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"'  does not have a key when I try to get it by using

```
IDictionary<string, string> nameSpaces = GetXmlNamespaces(xmlFilePath);
```

Comment: Ned to see sample of data.  Using Xml Linq there are ways of ignoring the namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using localName
refer this question:
[Select node without namespace with XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15139979/select-node-without-namespace-with-xpath)

Someone had commented this and now it's gone but it worked for me. So here I'm posting the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dynamically searching for the used namespace, you can instead find a node without the namespace information.

Have a look at the Q&A's which describe this solution

- [SelectSingleNode without namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472098/selectsinglenode-without-namespace/1474968)
- [Select node without namespace with XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15139979/select-node-without-namespace-with-xpath)
- [How to ignore namespace when selecting XML nodes with XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402310/how-to-ignore-namespace-when-selecting-xml-nodes-with-xpath)